# htaccess need help to rectify code

Tags: .htaccess

i have following urls (nornal and user friendly)

**Normal Urls:**

```
http://myweb.com/en/search/search.php?search_name=white&mydropdown=All+Categories

{and with page numbers}

http://myweb.com/en/search/search.php?search_name=white&mydropdown=All+Categories&pno=3
```

**friendly Urls:**

```
http://myweb.com/en/search/?search_name=white&mydropdown=All+Categories

{and with page numbers}

http://myweb.com/en/search/?search_name=white&mydropdown=All+Categories&pno=3
```

i have following htaccess, but it does not work...maybe its not correctly coded. its taking me back in en/index.php intead of en/search/search.php

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ en/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^en/search/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /en/search/search.php?search_name=$1&mydropdown=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks help me!
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why is there $1 twice in your redirect url?

I have a feelign that the first rule will match also "search". so it will use that. Try reversing the rule order.

Comment: programmers=errors..lol...what do you think could be the problem

Comment: try moving the more complex rule on top of the simpler. I think the simpler matches also the more complex one.

Comment: markus, the problem is that the htaccess file always take me to index.php even the url is search/search.php

Comment: yes taht is because search/search php will match the rule for index.php also. So you need to put the more complex rule first and then stop evaluation if it matches

Comment: and btw. for apache there were some debug options to track the redirecting. cant remember what they were. it will print out what rule matched and so-on.

Comment: RewriteLog "/myfolder/mylogfile.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 3

Comment: did you try to reverse order of those rules or removing the index.php redirect?

Comment: good suggestion...seems works fine...let me fully test it....(index.php rule removed )thanks